# Only can post values with one submit button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, post, form-submit

I have 2 submit buttons in a form like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z3vmvcc1/). When I click the `Check`-button it sent post data, that looks like this:

`{name=AName&IPAddress=123.456.7.89&StreamAddress=http://stream.com&username=admin&password=admin&check=Check}`

The action, which the data is sent to, can be seen in the JSFiddle link (in the CSS section) above.

When the user clicks the `Check`-button it will call, after the post, the javascript function `enableEditing(<boolean>)`, where the boolean is based on the result if the values are valid or not. If the values are valid, it will disable all inputs except the `Save`- and `Edit`-button.

When the user clicks the `Save`-button after the inputs are disabled, it won't send all of the form data. It only sends the button value, like this: `{save=Save}`.

I've tried to switch the disable function, so the `Check`-button is by default disabled and the `Save`-button is not. But that just switched the button value in the post data.

Does someone know what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: disabled controls value is not posted

Comment: Is that seriously it? It has to be disabled.. Is there anyway to post those values while there are disabled? Or another work around?

Comment: you can use hidden fields, for that when  they are disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="save" value="YourDesiredValue" />
```

You may want to add the hidden input dynamically with jquery but don't forget that you must add it to the form:

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="save" />").val('somevalue').appendTo($('form'));
```

Comment: You mean, like, putting all values into one hidden input and get them at the post data?

Comment: yes put the values of the disabled inputs in hidden inputs

Comment: it doesn't make any difference with your current code hackers could also enable the button using inspect element and even change its value. for its security you must think of something else

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that :P Thanks anyways :)